# FIWARE IoT Agent-UL freezes up when delete a device that does not exists

Tags: fiware

I have problems when I try to remove a FIWARE IoT Agent UL device using the REST API.

If I try to delete a device that exists, the service returns an HTTP code 204 and everything works as expected.

However, if I try to delete a device that does NOT exist, the service "hangs up" and I do not get any response from it.

This is the output of the node app, related to the service request that I made:

```
time=2018-03-22T14:30:39.225Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-  82b912df1ff0 | trans=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.GenericMiddlewares | srv=foo | subsrv=/bar | msg=Request for path [/iot/devices/641tvjjr] from [localhost:4061] | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-03-22T14:30:39.226Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | trans=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | srv=foo | subsrv=/bar | msg=Removing device register in Device Service | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-03-22T14:30:39.226Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | trans=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBDeviceRegister | srv=foo | subsrv=/bar | msg=Looking for entity with id [641tvjjr]. | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-03-22T14:30:39.228Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | trans=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBDeviceRegister | srv=foo | subsrv=/bar | msg=Entity [641tvjjr] not found. | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-03-22T14:30:39.229Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | trans=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Alarms | srv=foo | subsrv=/bar | msg=Raising [MONGO-ALARM]: undefined | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-03-22T14:30:39.230Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | trans=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DomainControl | srv=foo | subsrv=/bar | msg=TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of undefined | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-03-22T14:30:39.230Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | trans=9dff81b8-2cbe-4236-9bdc-82b912df1ff0 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DomainControl | srv=foo | subsrv=/bar | msg=response-time: 5 | comp=IoTAgent
```

I'm working with a single service, with values of Fiware-Service: "foo" and Fiware-ServicePath: "/bar", devices in that service and the default agent configuration file. Also, I am using the [1.6.0 release of IoT Agent UL](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/tree/release/1.6.0), which by the way is the latest version.

Everything else works correctly, device creation, devices listing, send measurements, etc. Everything except the elimination of a device that does not exist.

Has this happened to someone? It seems very strange to me and I can not believe that it is the first person that tries to erase a device that does not exist.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those who share the same question as me:

Apparently it's an open [issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/issues/587) in [node lib](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib) project.

> the api should return a 404, but it seems that an exception is not capture somewhere and because of that infinite response time is caused.

Fortunately there is a [pull request](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/pull/586) of the same guy who report the issue which fix it. In conclusion may be in next release it the problem will be resolved.